# Xamarin.Forms FFImageLoading SVGs to ESRI RunTimeImage

Tags: .net, svg, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading, esri-arc-engine

Converting an SVG to a `RunTimeImage`.

Essentially I'm trying to find a way to access the stream before it gets wrapped in an `SVGImageSource` so I can feed the byte array into the ArcGis `RunTimeImage` provided by Esri.

SVG's are kept in a PCL.

Comment: FFImageLoading is open source.  If you want to make a change to it's behavior you can fork it, do a PR, or just create your own local copy

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Ill probably just go with a png version of the image for the time being. I would prefer not to have to maintain a version of the package if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure this out for the time being, but the following code excerpt is a work around accessing the drawable folder of your android project using a png version of the image.

```
            int resourceId = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("atlaspinorange", "drawable", "Atlas.Locations");
        var icon = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Android.App.Application.Context.Resources, resourceId);
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        icon.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 50, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        var image = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.RuntimeImage(byteArray);
        mapView.LocationDisplay.CourseSymbol = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.PictureMarkerSymbol(image);
        mapView.LocationDisplay.DefaultSymbol = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.PictureMarkerSymbol(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource("yourFile.svg").WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver(200,200)).AsPNGStreamAsync();
```

?